# What are the possible values for target in a shortcut?

Tags: ip, lan, shortcuts, links

I tried `http://192.168.1.241/INDEX.php`, then `//192.168.1.241/INDEX.php`, and finally `192.168.1.241/INDEX.php`. None were valid. What I am trying to do is create a shortcut that points to the index on a LAN device.

Comment: The shortcut should be the full URL including http. Describe HOW you are creating the shortcut.

Comment: I tried right clicking on the DESKTOP, then New>Shortcut, but that didn't take me where I wanted to go. I have also tried editing an existing shortcut=no luck.

Comment: This is what it produces:

Comment: [{000214A0-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}]
Prop3=19,2
[InternetShortcut]
URL=http://192.168.1.248/
IDList=

Answer (score 0):

- Right-Click and select `New` -> `Shotrcut`.
- In the `Type the location of the item:` field, type:
  `http://192.168.1.241/INDEX.php'
- Click `Next`.
- In the `Type a name for this shortcut:` field, type a name for your
  shortcut.
- Click `Finish`.

If that doesn't work, `http://192.168.1.241/INDEX.php` isn't a valid address.

Comment: Windows insists on prefixing the string with C: which will screw up anything including url...

Comment: @NeilMurphy I don’t know what you are doing, but that is not true. I  do this all the time without issue. I did it to give you the step by step instructions. What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: You can call me a liar, but I wrote that immediately after having the experience. It is obvious from your earlier remarks that you have no experience with this.

Comment: @NeilMurphy Lol. I just about fell out of my chair. Thanks for the laugh. Good luck to you.